# Django Student-Teacher ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to model a Many to Many Teacher/Student relationship. Both the teachers and the students are objects of class Users (I edited out some unrelated fields). I'm having problems in understanding how the relationship should work.

Basically, I want to be able to do something like

```py
u1 = User.objects.get(pk=<student pk>)
u1.teachers.all()

u2 = User.objects.get(pk=<teacher pk>)
u2.students.all()
```

Is it possible?

After reading some docs and tutorials, this is how I defined the User class and the StudentTeacher relationship:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('teacher status', default=False)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField('self', through="StudentTeacher", through_fields=('student', 'teacher'), symmetrical=False)
    students = models.ManyToManyField('self', through="StudentTeacher", through_fields=('teacher', 'student'), symmetrical=False)

class StudentTeacher(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_teacher': True})
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teachers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_student': True})
```

This is what happens when I try to generate migrations (wiscom is the name of my application):

```
wiscom.StudentTeacher.student: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'StudentTeacher.student' clashes with field name 'User.teachers'.
    HINT: Rename field 'User.teachers', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'StudentTeacher.student'.
wiscom.StudentTeacher.student: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'StudentTeacher.student' clashes with field name 'User.teachers'.
    HINT: Rename field 'User.teachers', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'StudentTeacher.student'.
wiscom.StudentTeacher.teacher: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'StudentTeacher.teacher' clashes with field name 'User.students'.
    HINT: Rename field 'User.students', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'StudentTeacher.teacher'.
wiscom.StudentTeacher.teacher: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'StudentTeacher.teacher' clashes with field name 'User.students'.
    HINT: Rename field 'User.students', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'StudentTeacher.teacher'.
wiscom.User.students: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.students' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.teachers'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.students' or 'User.teachers'.
wiscom.User.teachers: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.teachers' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.students'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.teachers' or 'User.students'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have far too many relationships here. You don't need the StudentTeacher model, and you only need a single ManyToManyField.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    students = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='teachers')
```

Now your code works exactly as you have given.

Comment: Thanks, now it works as expected. As a follow-up, in the admin panel I'm trying to use a StackedInline in the User edit form for assigning students to teachers.

`class TeachersInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User
    max_num = 3
    extra = 1
`


but this results in 


`<class 'wiscom.admin.TeachersInline'>: (admin.E202) 'wiscom.User' has no ForeignKey to 'wiscom.User'.`

Do you know how to fix this?